# What is this cylindrical object?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, rebus

What is this cylindrical object with `radius z` and `height a`?

[image: cylinder]

---

Disclaimer: I heard this from my boss so thought I'd post it here.

Comment: It's a cylinder. Anything else?

Comment: @IAmInPLS You should be able to figure it out using a basic maths formula for a cylinder and some lateral thinking

Comment: copied..question

Comment: @AmruthA From where? My boss told it me so thought I'd post it here

Comment: from here [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=volume+of+cylinder+pizza&tbm=isch&imgil=QZhVbo4s1R5OxM%253A%253BSreGRLbw57qcuM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.pinterest.com%25252Fpin%25252F542754192565910307%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QZhVbo4s1R5OxM%253A%252CSreGRLbw57qcuM%252C_&usg=__nHunE3A90ABLKL_bf4knGDTksFg%3D&biw=1267&bih=899&ved=0ahUKEwjz9ILbqqjRAhVCro8KHSk_ABAQyjcIMg&ei=aNVsWPOgOsLcvgSp_oCAAQ#imgrc=QZhVbo4s1R5OxM%3A)

Comment: @AmruthA Either way I've seen copied questions posted here so I don't know what the problem is, I'll add a disclaimer into the question from where I heard it

Comment: wait.. what -_-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

> a pizza.
>  its volume is $pi \times z^2 \times a$ or pizza

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> Pizza

Because

> The volume of the cylinder is $Pi*z*z*a$

Comment: ninja'd.  by 35 seconds. :)

Comment: [from here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=volume+of+cylinder+pizza&tbm=isch&imgil=QZhVbo4s1R5OxM%253A%253BSreGRLbw57qcuM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.pinterest.com%25252Fpin%25252F542754192565910307%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QZhVbo4s1R5OxM%253A%252CSreGRLbw57qcuM%252C_&usg=__nHunE3A90ABLKL_bf4knGDTksFg%3D&biw=1267&bih=899&ved=0ahUKEwjz9ILbqqjRAhVCro8KHSk_ABAQyjcIMg&ei=aNVsWPOgOsLcvgSp_oCAAQ#imgrc=QZhVbo4s1R5OxM%3A)

Comment: @AmruthA Don't Google. Use Bing instead. Try looking at my profile description.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat,, ?? 3.5 years over ..whatz is this ??

Comment: @AmruthA You posted a Google link in your comment.